# How use php in HIghcharts?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts, phpmyadmin

I have this table on phpmyadmin (on the photo below). I want to show data on my website in a column chart using highcharts. In xAxis i want only years like this:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016']
    },
```

I try fo follow this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/ but i want load date from my file php and I don't know how put in the chart. Moreover, I don't have a value of men or women so to create the yAxis with the number of them I have to count men and woman and then add the result value in a variable?

```
yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Number of person'
    }
},
```

[image: table on my database on phpmyadmin]

Comment: with this query `select sum(case when tableName.sex='M' then 1 end) as sum_M, sum(case when tableName.sex='F' then 1 end) as sum_F, year(tableName.meal_date) as years from  tableName group by years` you can get count (M-F) for each year. pass this values in highchart